# Association in Symfony2 entity on field other than id does not display correctly in form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, entity

In an entity in my Symfony app there is an association that is not based on id's, but on serial numbers. The association looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var Department
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Department")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="department_serial", referencedColumnName="serial")
 */
protected $department;
```

When I create a form for this entity, I add the field Department like so:

```
->add('department', null, array
(
  'label' => 'Choose department',
  'required' => true,
  //some more...
))
```

The problem is that when the form is rendered I end up with wrong html list item values. The items seem to get auto numbering, as the values are not the actual department id's. Neither do they correspond to the serial numbers, which is my goal. This is an example of what I get:

```
<select id="someId" name="form[someName]">
  <option value="0">Department A</option>
  <option value="1">Department B</option>
  <option value="2">Department C</option>
  <option value="3">Department D</option>
  <option value="4">Department E</option>
  <option value="5">Department F</option>
</select>
```

The values of the list items above, should have been the serial number of each department. Since they are not, the link between the entity and its department seems lost and saving my form is not possible. (Choosing a department is required and departments with these serial numbers [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] do not exist.)

Hence, my question is: how can I indicate in my form type which property of the associated entity should be used as the value in the html list? I know that there is an option called "property" to change the label of each list item, but is there a way of changing its value?

Comment: What if you replace `null` with `entity`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. There is no change to the values of the list items. They still receive automatic numbers. However, now the first option (with value="0") is selected where none was selected before. (But there is no department with id or serial 0.)

Comment: Can you add the `Department` entity code?

Comment: As I found a solution, would you still like to see the Department Entity code? It is an extension of many other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it; the only way to do this was to make the serial property of the entity Department the id by adding @ORM\Id to its definition.

The actual id, which was a combined key made of two other properties, wasn't used anywhere but was there for legacy purposes. I now defined these fields using @uniqueConstraint.

In this case this was possible, but obviously this solution cannot be used if the id is also linked to in other places.

Somehow Symfony2 cannot reach non-id properties to use as list values for entities that are related to the entity a form is being built for. Seems like a bug to me...?

Comment: You didn't have any `@ORM\Id` in your `Departement` entity before?

Comment: I did, two even. But they were not set on the serial field, but on two fields called id and service. Apparently, Symfony2 could not handle this. As those two fields where not referenced anywhere in my Symfony2 app (like they were in the db the data came from), I could define them as a unique pair rather than an id. Next, I could define the serial as id, and then it all worked just fine. Still I believe Symfony2 should have been able to handle this without the serial field being an id, as it was correctly defined as an association.